# I am looking to write code apache rewrite urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to make my website's urls  seo friendly.

I want to get users from their names. 
eg we have a user with the name John Doe,

www.xyz.com/users/john-doe

```
RewriteRule    ^users/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    get_users_by_name.php?user_name=$1    [NC,L]    # Process users
```

My question is

how to handle this code if there are two users with the name John Doe?

Comment: You need to use some sort of unique userId also in your URLs or don't let them create duplicate names like email addresses.